# Install IBM MobileFirst server on windows instance

Tags: server, instance, ibm-mobilefirst

We have a windows instance and need to install IBM MobileFirst server in it & its console.
Please let me know the url to download the software, and steps to install it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Usually called Google, it will let you to the following location:

- Knowledge Center: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNJXP/welcome.html

Entering the keyword "install" will then lead you to: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/install?scope=SSHS8R_7.1.0&lang=en

Comment: I have done all those googling.. since i was unable to find the expected answer , I have posted here. If you know Exact answer(url) to my QUESTION (above) please let me know.

Comment: The second link provides installation instructions. That is the link, now you need to read through it.